# ¿Como configurar Data table Jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables, jquery-ui

Buenas quería saber si se puede configurar Data Table ya se como implementarlo 
pero quería saber si se puede elegir que cosas usar osea si solo quiero la paginación pues solo me salga la paginacion  si solo quiero el buscador que solo me salga el buscador intente quitando algunas opciones desde su script pero 
cuando las quitaba igual me la aparecía pero ahora en ingles

Se puede elegir que cosas quieres usar ?
Saben de un video donde lo explican? o un link de una pagina donde lo explican ?

Comment: https://datatables.net/manual/options tenés algunas de las opciones que mencionas.

Comment: Muchas gracias estare viendo la pagina

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esta es la pagina oficial:
[Jquery DataTables](https://datatables.net/)

Y te anexo algunos ejemplos:

- Configuracion por default de jquery DataTable

```js
$(document).ready(function() {

  var dataSet = [
    ["Tiger Nixon", "System Architect", "Edinburgh", "5421", "2011/04/25", "$320,800"],
    ["Garrett Winters", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "8422", "2011/07/25", "$170,750"],
    ["Ashton Cox", "Junior Technical Author", "San Francisco", "1562", "2009/01/12", "$86,000"],
    ["Cedric Kelly", "Senior Javascript Developer", "Edinburgh", "6224", "2012/03/29", "$433,060"],
    ["Airi Satou", "Accountant", "Tokyo", "5407", "2008/11/28", "$162,700"],
    ["Brielle Williamson", "Integration Specialist", "New York", "4804", "2012/12/02", "$372,000"],
    ["Herrod Chandler", "Sales Assistant", "San Francisco", "9608", "2012/08/06", "$137,500"],
    ["Rhona Davidson", "Integration Specialist", "Tokyo", "6200", "2010/10/14", "$327,900"],
    ["Colleen Hurst", "Javascript Developer", "San Francisco", "2360", "2009/09/15", "$205,500"],
    ["Sonya Frost", "Software Engineer", "Edinburgh", "1667", "2008/12/13", "$103,600"],
    ["Jena Gaines", "Office Manager", "London", "3814", "2008/12/19", "$90,560"],
    ["Quinn Flynn", "Support Lead", "Edinburgh", "9497", "2013/03/03", "$342,000"],
    ["Charde Marshall", "Regional Director", "San Francisco", "6741", "2008/10/16", "$470,600"],
    ["Haley Kennedy", "Senior Marketing Designer", "London", "3597", "2012/12/18", "$313,500"],
    ["Tatyana Fitzpatrick", "Regional Director", "London", "1965", "2010/03/17", "$385,750"],
    ["Michael Silva", "Marketing Designer", "London", "1581", "2012/11/27", "$198,500"],
    ["Paul Byrd", "Chief Financial Officer (CFO)", "New York", "3059", "2010/06/09", "$725,000"],
    ["Gloria Little", "Systems Administrator", "New York", "1721", "2009/04/10", "$237,500"],
    ["Bradley Greer", "Software Engineer", "London", "2558", "2012/10/13", "$132,000"],
    ["Dai Rios", "Personnel Lead", "Edinburgh", "2290", "2012/09/26", "$217,500"],
    ["Jenette Caldwell", "Development Lead", "New York", "1937", "2011/09/03", "$345,000"],
    ["Yuri Berry", "Chief Marketing Officer (CMO)", "New York", "6154", "2009/06/25", "$675,000"],
    ["Caesar Vance", "Pre-Sales Support", "New York", "8330", "2011/12/12", "$106,450"],
    ["Doris Wilder", "Sales Assistant", "Sidney", "3023", "2010/09/20", "$85,600"],
    ["Angelica Ramos", "Chief Executive Officer (CEO)", "London", "5797", "2009/10/09", "$1,200,000"],
    ["Gavin Joyce", "Developer", "Edinburgh", "8822", "2010/12/22", "$92,575"],
    ["Jennifer Chang", "Regional Director", "Singapore", "9239", "2010/11/14", "$357,650"],
    ["Brenden Wagner", "Software Engineer", "San Francisco", "1314", "2011/06/07", "$206,850"],
    ["Fiona Green", "Chief Operating Officer (COO)", "San Francisco", "2947", "2010/03/11", "$850,000"],
    ["Shou Itou", "Regional Marketing", "Tokyo", "8899", "2011/08/14", "$163,000"],
    ["Michelle House", "Integration Specialist", "Sidney", "2769", "2011/06/02", "$95,400"],
    ["Suki Burks", "Developer", "London", "6832", "2009/10/22", "$114,500"],
    ["Prescott Bartlett", "Technical Author", "London", "3606", "2011/05/07", "$145,000"],
    ["Gavin Cortez", "Team Leader", "San Francisco", "2860", "2008/10/26", "$235,500"],
    ["Martena Mccray", "Post-Sales support", "Edinburgh", "8240", "2011/03/09", "$324,050"],
    ["Unity Butler", "Marketing Designer", "San Francisco", "5384", "2009/12/09", "$85,675"]
  ];

  var columnDefs = [{
    title: "Name"
  }, {
    title: "Position"
  }, {
    title: "Office"
  }, {
    title: "Extn."
  }, {
    title: "Start date"
  }, {
    title: "Salary"
  }];

  var myTable;

  myTable = $('#example').DataTable({
    data: dataSet,
    columns: columnDefs
  });


});
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/css/jquery.dataTables.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script><script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.11/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="dataTable table table-striped" id="example">

  </table>
</div>
```

- Paginador:

Puedes configurar el paginador como se muestra en el siguietne link: [Paginadores alternativos jquery-datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/alt_pagination.html)

```
     //puedes deshabilitar el paginador
     $('#example').DataTable( {
         data: dataSet,
         columns: columnDefs,
         "paging":   false,
         "ordering": false,
         "info":     false
     } );
```

- Ordenar por alguna columna:

  ```
   $('#example').DataTable( {
       data: dataSet,
       columns: columnDefs,        
       "order": [[ 3, "desc" ]]//La 4 columna en orde descendente
   } );
  ```
- Quitar el filtro o buscador:

  ```
   $('#example').DataTable( {
       data: dataSet,
       columns: columnDefs,        
       "bFilter": false
   } );
  ```

En la liga oficial podras encontrar mas detalles dependiento de como quieras configurar tu datatable.

Saludos.